# How do I test the behavior of a function inside a component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

How do I test a function inside a component? (It affects the output of the function)

I have a function `shouldRender` that determines whether the component should be rendered. I have tried mounting the function and manually setting the props and state necessary but the function doesn't seem to be called correctly.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    shouldComponentRender(myProp, myState) {
        return myProp && myState;
    }

    render() {
        const shouldRender = shouldComponentRender(this.props.shouldRender, this.state.shouldRender);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {shouldRender && <div> .... <div>}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
wrapper.setProps({shouldRender: true});
wrapper.setState({shouldRender: true});
expect(wrapper.find(".someClassThatShouldExistIfItWorked").length).to.equal(1);
```

I'm using `mount` because I wanted to see something in `componentDidMount` but that's unrelated to this question.

The error I get at the last line is:

```
    AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1
```

Comment: try using `wrapper.update()` before expect and see if that changes outcome

Comment: when you debug that what is `wrapper.debug()` at line with `expect`? is your component really that simple? could it be `shouldComponentRender` just checks different props in your real code?